# Global Python Lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need some help with this function I'm stuck on.

I need to do three processes, one is to switch each player based on odd or even runs entered, which works but, I can't figure out how to replace and populate the `batsmanName` placeholder relevant to the `batsmanBatting` list and if a wicket is taken it changes to next element in the `batsmanName` list (it is added by user if a wicket is taken).

The final process is to add scores in `batsmanRun` relevant index to the batter batting, that is, if `batsmanBatting[4]` is 'T' then `batsmanRun[4]` should accumulate according.

I hope I've explained this clearly and makes sense, if not I could add more info, any help would be much appreciated.

```
def getRuns(totalScore):

    global batsmanName  #[] empty list a function adds a player if a wicket is taken
    global batsmanRun #[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] #accumulators 
    global batsmanBatting #['F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F'] 
    global batsmanOnField #['F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F']
    global wickets

    while(1):
        try:
            if(totalScore%2==0):
                print(batsmanBatting)
                runs=int(input("\nEnter runs for striker %s: " % batsmanName[0]))
                batsmanRun[0]+=runs
                print(batsmanRun)
            else:
                print(batsmanBatting)
                runs=int(input("\nEnter runs for striker %s: " % batsmanName[1]))
                batsmanRun[1]+=runs
                print(batsmanRun)
            if(runs<7):    
                return runs 
            else:
                print("Invalid run(s) entered. Please try again.")
        except Exception as err:
                print(err)
                print("Please try again.")
```

Comment: Any specific part? Or just general?

Comment: In general.. please could you answer the following ? where are the events happening from? Does this function only serve to modify the globals. In which case it is not good practice. you should modify the globals at positions where events are taking place. This function as an infinite loop will result in high cpu usage

Comment: As per your explanation, I have only a vague idea of what you are trying to accomplish. Maybe to someone familiar with that sport it is more obvious. You should probably try to break down your problem into smaller chunks: Who is the current player, what does she do when and why, something like that.

Comment: the getRuns() function occurs within a general loop designed for both TeamA and TeamB. wicketsOut() function is called first if a wicket is marked as -1 it calls the addPlayer() function where it prompts the users to add a player to the global list shown batsmanName[], if a wicket is not marked as -1 it goes to the getRuns() function shown above. Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: I am familiar with cricket, As far as i can understand. You have to maintain the following data: 1) Who are the current batsmen(striker and non-striker) 2) Their scores 3) Scores for all batsmen. Could you tell me where you maintain all this in your code ?

Comment: Also, what is the hardest problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Hi mike, pretty much this part has got me stumped. Yes, I'm a beginner :). Hi Acid, this part is actually the part that is going to take care of all the scoring and switching hence why the lists. Any hints or tips guys would be so much helpful as I'm not making much progress so far.

Comment: Should I post a URL from paste bin showing my entire program?

Answer (score 1):

To add a name to the `batsmanName` list, you do

```
batsmanName.append('Mr Batsman')
```

If it is a true placeholder, then don't use a list, use `None` or an empty string. In that case you update it by assigning it:

```
batsmanName = 'Mr Batsman'
```

For your second question (you really should pose separate questions separately) it is unclear what "if batsmanBatting[4] is 'T' then batsmanRun[4] should accumulate according" means, but I guess it means this:

```
for num, state in enumerate(batsmanBatting):
    if state == 'T':
        batsmanRun[num] += 1
```

There are probably better ways of doing that. Or not, I don't know cricket.

Comment: Hi Lennart, adding the name to the batsmanName list is no problem it's populating the placeholder in the getRuns() function after it has been added. You are sort of correct I think, in cricket there is 11 players in total, 2 players on the field at one time. If a player is struck out the players position in the list batsmanBatting turns to 'F' and the next value turns to 'T' to signify the next player is batting. batsmanField signifys two players on the field, so it should look like this batsmanOnField ['T', 'T', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F']

Comment: Yep, lennart was right, I need to use nested for loops I think, if state == Y then add runs to that player. Now I got to modify it, so the name only appears if state == Y ..Any ideas guys?

Comment: @user1291271: I don't understand what the difference is between "adding the name to the batsmanName list" and "populating the batsmanName placeholder". Adding the name to the list *is* populating the placeholder. Same thing. You need to be clearer.

Comment: @Lennart: the function has two inputs i.e. the two players currently batting, if a wicket is taken it calls another function that asks the user to input a name of the next player e.g.  if(wickets==9):
        player3=input(str('Please enter the new batsman at the striker end: '))
        batsmanName.insert(2,player3)
        batsmanOnField[2]='T'

Comment: @Lennart, what im struggling to do is then replace the batsmanName in the getRun() function shown above with that new player just added

Comment: @user1291271: Well, then thing is I've already told you how to do that, so you need to be more specific. You have to show exactly what you are trying to do, and explain why you don't think it's working.